# How can I be sure a digraph is not defined by Vim?

Tags: digraphs

I am trying to enter a latin cross (`✝`, Unicode `271d`) into a document. I can't find a pre-defined digraph for this. I am able to enter such a character with `<ctrl-v>u271d` or I can define a new digraph in my `.vimrc` like so: `digraph \|- 10013`.

But before I'd do that I'd like to know if there is really no pre-defined digraph for the latin cross. How can I verify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`:digraphs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/digraph.txt.html#%3adigraphs) command to get a list of all defined digraphs. This isn't very easy to search, but we can use [`:redir`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3aredir) to store it to a file:

```
:redir all_digraphs
:digraphs
:redir END
:e all_digraphs
```

And we can now search the file:

```
/<C-v>u271d
```

which gives us:

```
E385: search hit BOTTOM without match for: ✝
```

which confirms that this characters isn't a pre-defined digraph.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such digraph defined by default. You can review available digraphs at `:help digraph-table`. The listing includes hex and decimal values as well as the name of the character, so you can easily search for an entry, for instance with `:help digraph-table|/0x271d` or `:help digraph-table|/CROSS`. The closest ones I see by value are

```
✓   OK  2713    10003   CHECK MARK
✗   XX  2717    10007   BALLOT X
✠   -X  2720    10016   MALTESE CROSS
```

and I suppose the closest one visually is

```
†   /-  2020    8224    DAGGER
```

Answer (score 2):

I made the [unicode plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) that helps with finding digraphs. You can use the command `:Digraphs cross` to search for a digraph whose name contains cross. Or when on the char, issue the command `:Unicodename` and it will output the digraph for that char. There are other similar commands as well, so check the help.

Answer (score 2):

So... You want an easy way to determine if a character is already defined as a digraph in Vim?

The easiest way I know to do this is to place your cursor over the character in question and then type `ga` .  At the bottom of the Vim window you'll not only see the character, its decimal value, its hexadecimal value, and its octal value, but if it's a defined digraph you'll also see the character-pair that defines the digraph.

To illustrate, try this:

1. Copy this text and paste it into Vim:  `e è é ê ĕ ¿ ?`
2. In Vim, position your cursor over each of those characters and type:  `ga`
3. For `e` and `?`, you should see a line at the bottom that lists its Unicode values in decimal, hexadecimal, and octal.
4. But for the `è é ê ĕ ¿` characters, you should *also* see a `Digr` value that tells you what character-pair defines the digraph.

For example, when I put my cursor over `?` and press `ga`, I see:

`<¿> 191, Hex 00bf, Oct 277, Digr ?I`

That final `Digr ?I` means that if you type `<C-K>?I` while in INSERT mode, Vim will output a `¿` character.

Note that a character may have more than one digraph associated with it.  For instance, the `¿` can by typed with both `<C-K>?I` and `<C-K>~?` but the output of `ga` will only show you one of them.

---

Let me try this out on the Latin Cross:

When I position my cursor on `✝` and type `ga`, I see this at the bottom of my Vim window:

`<✝> 10013, Hex 271d, Octal 23435`

Since there is no `Digr` text in that output, I can assume that the Latin Cross does not have a pre-defined digraph.